# <Route> not show the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, jsx

I'm got issue when i making navbar using raect but when i put `<Route>` component that make the web view blank, but if i remove the `<Route>`  Is someone can helpme to fix my issue?

this is my code on App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">Logo</Link>
          <div className="navbar-nav">
            <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/premium">About Me</Link>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <Route path="/" component={() => <h4>Home</h4>}></Route>
      <Route path="/premium" component={() => <h4>About Me</h4>}></Route>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` is installed? Check by running `npm list react-router-dom` in the project's root directory.

Comment: Use react location. There are too many headaches with React Router. Reach Router was amazing, it was killed off

Comment: @Pushkin Uh, Reach Router was merged into `react-router`, v6.

Comment: Yea, it's merged, but most of the things I loved about it are no longer working in v6. That's huge let down. So, it's dead in my book. **RIP Reach Router**

Answer (score 2):

Things to note:

1. Route needs to be direct children of Routes
2. Children should be passed to `element` prop, instead of `component`
3. `element` prop expects a React Node, not a function

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route, 
  Routes,
  Link 
} from 'react-router-dom'
```

```
 <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">Logo</Link>
          <div>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/premium">About Me</Link>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<h4>Home</h4>}></Route>
      <Route path="/premium" element={<h4>About Me</h4>}></Route>
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

*removed `className` for readability*

Comment: It works but  the `Route` not showing component `<h4>Home</h4>}>` or `<h4>About Me</h4>}>`

Comment: Fixed a typo, it should work now. `element` expects a React Node

Answer (score 0):

Based on OPs comment about the routes working but the routed content not rendering I will assume `react-router-dom@6` is installed and working. The `Route` component API changed quite a bit from v5. `Route` components can only be rendered by the `Routes` component (*the spiritual successor to RRDv5's `Switch` component*) or by another `Route` component in the case of nested routes. Gone are the `component`, and `render` and `children` function props, replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

- Wrap the `Route` components in a `Routes` component
- Render the routed content on the `Route` component's `element` prop

Example:

```
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,  // <-- import Routes component
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">Logo</Link>
          <div className="navbar-nav">
            <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/premium">About Me</Link>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <Routes> // <-- wrap routes in `Routes` component
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<h4>Home</h4>} // <-- JSX on element prop
        />
        <Route
          path="/premium"
          element={<h4>About Me</h4>} // <-- JSX on element prop
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

For making a navbar you don't need the BrowserRouter or Route components,
just the Link from react-router-dom

as shown in the quick start guide:
[reactrouter.com/QuickStart#Navigation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation)

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> |{" "}
        <Link to="about">About</Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

also, the navbar should be put as an element attribute of a Route
following this approach:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
          <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
          <Route path="new" element={<NewTeamForm />} />
          <Route index element={<LeagueStandings />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```